# How is getBoundindClientRect y value a minus value on a fixed element iphone keyboard is open?

Tags: javascript, mobile, keyboard, viewport, sticky

I've found that on iphones, when getBoundingClientRect is called on elements which should always stay within the layout viewport they report a minus y values.

Here's a simple replication example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">  
  
  <style>  
    #position-fixed-el {  
      position: fixed;  
      top: 0;  
      left: 10px;  
      right: 10px;  
      background-color: orange;  
      height: 10px;  
    }  
      
    [contenteditable]{  
      height: 100px;  
      border: 1px solid black;  
      margin-top: 80vh;  
    }  
  
  </style>  
  
</head>  
  
<body>  
  
<div id="position-fixed-el"></div>  
  
<div contenteditable="true"></div>  
  
<script>  
    const positionFixedEl = document.getElementById("position-fixed-el")  
    visualViewport.addEventListener("resize", () => {  
        console.log(positionFixedEl.getBoundingClientRect().y)  
    })  
</script>  
</body>  
</html>
```

On iphones, if you click on the content editable you'll see that the `y` coord is a minus figure. This does not occur on Android devices that I've seen.

MDN's says that the coordinates are relative to the viewport. My understanding is that this the layout viewport and not the visual viewport.

If the coords are for the layout viewport and we have a `position:fixed;top:0` element which is also stuck to the top of the layout viewport then it should always return a `y` value of 0 but it doesn't.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I've run your example here but I cannot duplicate your error. I always get 0 as the answer.

```js
const positionFixedEl = document.getElementById("position-fixed-el");
const boundingBoxResult = document.getElementById('bounding-box-result');

function logBoundingBox (){
  const box = positionFixedEl.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log( box.y );
  boundingBoxResult.innerHTML = JSON.stringify( box, null, '  ' ).replace(/\n/gi,'<br>');
}

visualViewport.addEventListener("resize", logBoundingBox);
logBoundingBox();
```

```css
#position-fixed-el {  
      position: fixed;  
      top: 0;  
      left: 10px;  
      right: 10px;  
      background-color: orange;  
      height: 10px;  
    }  
      
    [contenteditable]{  
      height: 100px;  
      border: 1px solid black;  
      margin-top: 80vh;  
    }
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

<div id="position-fixed-el"></div>
<div id="bounding-box-result"></div>
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a crucial piece of information that I've only see this occur on iphones, Android devices don't have this issue